# Placing a sprite at a coordinate using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, coordinates, sprite

I am currently trying to place wall sprites at certain coordinates based on a string from a text file.

What I would like for it to do is read the textfile(getting the string from it). Then based on the character at the index of the string, place a wall sprite at certain coordinates. If it is not a certain character, then just skip placing a wall sprite and move on.

In this case, I want to use # to place a wall. It wont let me post images yet so ill draw it.

```
TEXTFILE:

###...
```

As you can see, I place 3 #'s to tell the script I want 3 walls and thats it.
The 3 dots after them are not #, so there should be no wall placed.

In this case it works, as it shows up in my game like such

```
"# = Wall"
"P = Player"

###

  P
```

But when I try to make a hole in my wall using this kind of placement

```
TEXTFILE:

###...###
```

It shows up in my game like such, with no hole in between the two sections of #'s

```
"# = Wall"
"P = Player"

#########

  P
```

Here is my full main script so far(minus classes), let me know if you need more information. Thanks again!

```
#I - Import and Initialize
import pygame, IceBackground, Player, Wall, IceBlock
pygame.init()

#D - Display Configuration
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 600))


def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sliders")

    #E - Entities(Just background for now)
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((213, 220, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    icebackground = IceBackground.IceBG()
    player = Player.Box(90, 150)
    iceblock = IceBlock.Box(90, 0)

    coords = []
    with open("TestLevel.txt") as file:
        testLevel = file.read()
        print(testLevel)

        file.close()

    strLength = len(testLevel)

    xcoord = 0
    ycoord = 0

    for i in range(strLength):
        print(i)
        coordInsert = (xcoord, ycoord)
        coords.insert(i, coordInsert) 

        if testLevel[i] == "#":    
            print("Wall placed!")
            print(coordInsert)
            print("\n")
            walls = [Wall.Box(xcoord, ycoord) for xcoord, ycoord in coords]
        elif testLevel[i] != "#":
            print("Nothing placed")
            print(coordInsert)
            print("\n")
        xcoord += 30



    #iceblock = [IceBlock.Box(xcoord, ycoord) for xcoord, ycoord, in coords]


    backgroundSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(icebackground)
    wallSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(*walls)
    playerSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

    #A - Assign values to key variables
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True

    #L - Set up the Main Loop
    while keepGoing:

    #T - Timer to set frame rate
        clock.tick(60)

    #E - Event Handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

        hitWalls = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wallSprites, False)
        if hitWalls:
            if player.dx > 0:
                player.dx = 0
                player.rect.centerx = player.rect.centerx - 10

            if player.dx < 0:
                player.dx = 0
                player.rect.centerx = player.rect.centerx + 10

            if player.dy > 0:
                player.dy = 0
                player.rect.centery = player.rect.centery - 10

            if player.dy < 0:
                player.dy = 0
                player.rect.centery = player.rect.centery + 10

    #R - Refresh Display
        backgroundSprites.update()
        wallSprites.update()
        playerSprites.update()

        backgroundSprites.draw(screen)
        wallSprites.draw(screen)
        playerSprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe because you replace your whole wall list once instantiating a wall in a list comprehension.

Comment: -KSFT in the first example only 3 wall sprites and a player sprites. In the second one it prints 9 wall sprites and a player. According to the second textfile, there should be only 6 sprites, with a gap inbetween the two groups of three.



-Malik would that cause it to place sprites in places where it shouldnt?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment ycoord by 30 when xcoord == 270. If you don't do so, all your sprite will be aligned.